# Why must these regressions on a constant equal the mean?

Tags: regression, self-study, mathematical-statistics

Show that the OLS, MoR and RoM estimators for the 
regression of a variable on a constant (ie a variable which always takes the value 
one) are all equal to just the mean of that variable.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I added the "homework" tag because this seems like homework. If that is not right, feel free to remove it

Comment: Although "OLS" is common enough to be recognizable, what specifically do "MoR" and "RoM" stand for?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint,  If you are fitting a regression with only a constant then you are fitting a horizontal line to the data.  Think about the criteria that the regression models are using to find the "best" fit and then work out what value (height of the horizontal line) will fit that criteria.

Comment: +1. And note that some forms of regression (such as a pure $L^1$ regression) will *not* produce the mean in this circumstance, so the conclusion actually says something about these particular estimators.